RealityKit VideoMaterial renders pink on iOS 18 but works on iOS 17 – How to fix?
I am creating a video screen in RealityKit for an AR app. My code works correctly on iOS 17, but on iOS 18, the VideoMaterial renders as pink stripes. An Apple engineer suggested this could indicate the material is not being applied correctly.
I’ve reviewed my code, but I can’t find where the issue lies. Could this be due to changes in RealityKit or AVPlayer behavior in iOS 18?
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a plane for the video screen.

Apply a VideoMaterial using AVPlayerItem.

Anchor the model entity to an ARImageAnchor.


Expected Outcome:
The video should play as a material on the plane in RealityKit.
Actual Outcome:
On iOS 18, the plane appears pink, indicating the VideoMaterial isn’t applied.
What I’ve Tried:

Verified the video URL is correct.

Checked that the AVPlayerItem and VideoMaterial are initialised correctly.

Ensured the AVPlayer is playing the video.


What changes in iOS 18 could affect VideoMaterial rendering in RealityKit, and how can I fix this issue?
// Create Video Screen
private func createVideoScreen(width: Float, height: Float, url: URL, uuid: UUID) -> ModelEntity {
    let screenMesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: width, height: height)
    let videoItem = createVideoItem(with: url)
    let videoMaterial = createVideoMaterial(with: videoItem, uuid: uuid)
    let videoScreenModel = ModelEntity(mesh: screenMesh, materials: [videoMaterial])
    return videoScreenModel
}

// Create Video Item
private func createVideoItem(with url: URL) -> AVPlayerItem {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    return videoItem
}
// Create Video Material
private func createVideoMaterial(with videoItem: AVPlayerItem, uuid: UUID) -> VideoMaterial {
    let player = AVPlayer()
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    let videoMaterial = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: player)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: videoItem)
    player.play()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
        player.seek(to: .zero)
        player.play()
    }
    videoPlayers[uuid] = player
    return videoMaterial
}

// Place Video Screen
private func placeVideoScreen(videoScreen: ModelEntity, imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor, uuid: UUID) {
    guard let arView = arView else { return }
    
    let imageAnchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: imageAnchor)
    let rotationAngle = simd_quatf(angle: GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90), axis: SIMD3(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
    videoScreen.setOrientation(rotationAngle, relativeTo: imageAnchorEntity)
    imageAnchorEntity.addChild(videoScreen)
    
    arView.scene.addAnchor(imageAnchorEntity)
    activeAnchors[uuid] = imageAnchorEntity
}


You're absolutely right, neither VideoMaterial nor  VideoPlayerComponent can play video in iOS 18+ RealityKit scene. Instead of a video, the screen displays the notorious purple color (saw this in earlier RK versions), although the sound is reproduced properly. Due to internal AVPlayer errors in iOS video, the Simulator does not start at all. I tried both .mov and .mp4 files. Waiting for updates!  ))
